# Obtener qué números de un array son divisibles por 2 en PHP

Tags: php, array, funciones, loops

Tengo un array generado con números aleatorios, y debo obtener cuáles son divisibles por 2, sin embargo, al ejecutar el script de PHP  me muestra el siguiente error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Mi código es este:

```
function divisores($arrayalet){
    $i = 0;

    foreach ($arrayalet as $x)
        if ($x % 2 == 0){
           $i++;
           echo "$i </br>";
        }

    return $i;
}

$divi2 = divisores($arraylet);
```

Comment: Podrías poner el codigo donde se setea la variable $arrayalet? Parece que el foreach es correcto... solo se me ocurre que no le esté llegando un array como se espera

Comment: Adjunto mi código completo: http://pastebin.com/Baj3iZwm

Comment: En el ejemplo (con un array correcto) no estás devolviendo los números pares si no la cantidad de números pares. De cualquier modo, el error indica que $arrayalet no es iterable, habría que ver cómo lo has definido.

Comment: Sin embargo en este código sí me funcionaba: ``` function cincos(array $arrayalet) { 
            $i = 0; 
            foreach ($arrayalet as $x) 
            if ($x = 5); 
            return $i; 
            }
            $cincos = cincos($arrayalet);
        echo "La cantidad de cincos es ".$cincos."</br>";```

Comment: @ras212 prueba con `<?php

function divisores($arrayalet){
         $i = 0;
         foreach ($arrayalet as $x)
            if ($x % 2 == 0){
                $i++;
                
            }
        return $i;
     }
     
     $array=[1,2,3,4,5,6];
     echo divisores($array);`

Comment: La variable de entrada es $arraylet o $array**a**let?

Comment: Solucionado, me faltó una a, @Muriano, ponlo en la respuesta.

Comment: @ras212 viendo tu codigo completo, tiene razón @Muriano . Estás pasando la variable `$arraylet` la cual no tiene definida, línea 80 del pastebin

Comment: Ahora que lo pienso, me cuenta los pares, pero no me muestra cuáles son

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El array de entrada es incorrecta , no está correctamente formada :

```
$array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10];
```

Si que me funciona y sin escribir nada complicado :

```
foreach ($array as $a)
  if($a % 2 == 0)
    print_r($a."\n");
```

Comment: Vamos a ver, el script me devuelve esto al ejecutarlo, http://imgur.com/a/sNOj4, si el array estuviera malñ declarado no debería de mostrármelo